# String at end of EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is it possible to make an `EditText` that shows an uneditable string at the end of the user input?

For example, I could have an EditText where I ask for the user's weight in pounds.  I know the units has to be pounds, so if the user enters in "150", then the EditText shows "150 lb", where " lb" is the uneditable string appended at the end of user input.

I'm trying to extend the `EditText` class, but the `TextView` `setText()` method is final, so it can't be overridden, which makes things difficult.

Comment: You can use a onKey* listener that sets the text for the user. So no matter what they enter, you overwrite it with your modified text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think before the user tries to enter the data, use hint

```
<EditText android:hint="@string/hint" />
```

Once the user completely enters the text and presses the Done button or focuses on the next component on the UI, you can append Lb on the EditText.

```
Use onFocusChange() listener
```

Comment: Ok, I tried that and it works well enough.  However, I notice that there are several different types of listeners that I could potentially use for this solution for EditText:

`setOnClickListener()`
`setOnEditorActionListener()`
`setOnFocusChangeListener()`
`setOnKeyListener()`
`setOnTouchListener()`

Which one would be the best for this situation?  I know the EditText always comes into focus when the activity starts, which might interfere with the onFocusChangeListener

Comment: For example, if you have two edittext boxes, one for username, another for password, and you want to append some text for username field. Once the user types his username and focuses on password editext box, listen to it and append the text on username edittext.